# How to fix CMake CMP0018 warning?

Tags: c++, cmake

I use `CMake 2.8.12.2` to build my project (in Mac), which contains two modules as following:

```
project
   |
   |____ module_a
   |
   |____ module_b
```

When `module_a` and `module_b` are built as `STATIC` libraries, there is no warning when `cmake` `project`. But if I have changed the modules as `SHARED` libraries, I encountered the warning:

```
  Variable CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS has been modified.  CMake will ignore
  the POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE target property for shared libraries and will
  use the CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS variable instead.  This may cause
  errors if the original content of CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS was removed.

  Policy CMP0018 is not set: Ignore CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_<Lang>_FLAGS
  variable.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0018" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

Which makes no sense for me, since I never dealt with `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS`.

How to fix this warning? I don't prefer ignoring it.

Comment: tried to delete cmake cache and rerun?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cmake_policy` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3acmake_policy) to select the policy you want.